# How to add external configuration details in wso2

Tags: java, wso2, rabbitmq

I want to add RabbitMQ localhost, port, username, password details directly in wso2, instead of sending through a Java program.

I've a Java webservice (which will produce war file). As of now we've mentioned in the `workflow.properties` in `Main/resources/`.

Now when there is a change in RabbitMQ details, every time I've to update the war file. Instead I want to handle this in ws02 side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can't get this done directly from ESB Since your service is a external webservice. There are wo ways you can do this.

1. Read the configurations from a external file and use them in your webapp.Then you only need to change this file and not the whole war file.
2. Save the necessary configurations in the Registry (Which comes with WSO2 ESB) and then access the Registry resources from there. You can refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance500/Accessing+Registry+Remotely+through+API).

Comment: is it possible to give me an example. The link seems to be so theoritical, I'm new to ws02 and RabbitMq

Comment: @harikrishan Can you give more details on your use case. You can update your original question.